# Japenese results while searching with english text and vice versa in apache lucene.

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, hibernate-search

Is there any support in Apache lucene, in which we can get results in multiple languages ???

For example:
 I want to search with English text and get results in Japanese also and vice versa.

Please help.

Comment: so you want an automatic translation? doubt vanilla lucene has that. Doubt any library/tool has such capabilities.

Comment: It can be achieved if I index my saved text in both English and Japanese and link these but I doubt its possibility with Apache Lucene. Somehow I need a translation API to achieve this.

Comment: what I meant is that there are no reliable real-time translation APIs/libraries. I mean look at google translate, it's bad still it's one of the best things you can get... Especially when you're trying to translate languages which are so different.